# iCloud and Email and syncing

Tags: iphone, ipad, data-synchronization, icloud, imac

I am a little bit confused as to how best to setup my devices to have the best battery life and best syncing options.

I have an iMac, iPad mini & iPhone 5.

Currently I use Google Apps (Gmail) to store my email, calendar and contacts. I want to use some of the other iCloud functions such as Notes and Reminders syncing.

I figure it was best to switch everything to iCloud except my email. But that still requires me to be syncing two accounts on my iPhone and iPad (one exchange account for email and one account for iCloud) which I assume would drain the battery alot.

Is there any way I can have this setup such that I am only syncing one account and everything is pushed to my devices and in sync?

Comment: Why do you think it will affect battery usage a lot, I would doubt you would see any change

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can forward any email from your exchange account to icloud!

So you don't have to sync your exchange–emails sepperatly!

Go to the email settings in your exchange account,there must be an option where you can forward any incoming email to another address.

When you want to transfer all your old emails as well:use mail on Mac, create your two accounts and move all exchange emails to an icloud folder!

You can also send from your exchange-account: create your account in the settings, but disable the option to synchronise the emails.

When you now want to send a new email, you have the option from which account you want to send it.